# Google place rank by distance

Tags: google-places-api

What's wrong with this request? I cannot come up with this issue.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?rankby=distance&location=49.4456945,10.1120762&language=IT&sensor=true&key=my-api-key

If I delete the rankby parameter and add radius, it works.

PS:  instead of my-api-key there is a valid api key, declared in the console.

Answer (score 2):

As pushbit say,

> If rankby=distance is specified, then one or more of keyword, name, or types is required.

If you want to retieve each place use "**type=establishment**"

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?types=establishment&rankby=distance&location=49.4456945,10.1120762&language=IT&sensor=true&key=your-key

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests) states under 'Optional parameters > rankby > distance', "One or more of keyword, name, or types is required."  Add one or more of those parameters to your request and the server will send an `OK` response.

Comment: Ok but how can I ask for all type of places with every kind of name sorted by distance in a given radius then?

Comment: Theoretically, you could use the `types` parameter and specify all of the valid values.

Comment: Yes but... I hope there would be a better solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

`rankby` — Specifies the order in which results are listed. Note that rankby must not be included if radius (described under Required parameters above) is specified.

[Reference-Place Search API Doc](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

Answer (score 0):

If you use rankby=distance, you need to add at least name or types. I suggest to add types=point_of_interest.

Ps: types=establishment is deprecated, see: [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

> &key=my-api-key

You need to add API_KEY from [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

Comment: I forgot to say that instead of my-api-key there is a valid api key, declared in the console.