# Google Places Api rankby=distance not working

Tags: json, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using Google places api for get only some nearest places from my location, but some results not shows at all (for example tbilisimarriot and courtyardbymarriot results)  and also list isn't shows correctly from nearest to longest places. My request url is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.711586,44.748187&rankby=distance&keyword=(tbilisimarriot)OR(courtyardbymarriot)OR(ambassadori)OR(mercure)OR(ibishotel)OR(holidayinn)OR(cityavenue)OR(hotelcitycenter)OR(museumhotel)OR(hotelastoria)OR(citadelnarikala)OR(iotahotel)OR(preferencehualing)&key=***
```

Am I using url incorrectly? What is a problem? Thank you!

Comment: I've played around with this and I can't figure it out either. If I search 'Marriot', I can get both Marriots, but if I search 'Marriot|Mercure', the first Marriot disappears. Sorry :(

Comment: I'm afraid the `OR` syntax is not supported in Places API. I haven't seen it documented anywhere.

Comment: I haven't seen it in google documentation too, but I made a search and people uses it. How can I better get results without OR? I'm builing phonegap app and I need to get only some places and not all what is nearby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rankby` — Specifies the order in which results are listed. Note that `rankby` must not be included if `radius` (described under Required parameters above) is specified.

If `rankby=distance` (described under Optional parameters below) is specified, then one or more of `keyword`, `name`, or `type` is required.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50817579/8646587